# How do I solve the problem of interval and margin for interpolating in VMStools?

Tags: r, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate tacsat data that has a time interval mainly of 60 minutes but the function returns an error when trying to find the VMS point (see below).

> interpolation <- interpolateTacsat(tacsatB,interval=60,margin=30,res=100,method="cHs",params=list(fm=0.2,distscale=20,sigline=0.2,st=c(2,6)),headingAdjustment=0)
> Error in findEndTacsat(SI_DATIM[idx], startVMS = startidx, interval, margin): found endVMS point not within interval range

Already checked data that is in betwen the time interval ± margin and the tacsat columns contain the necessary information for interpolation. However, the error keeps persisting although I also try to change interval and margin parametres. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Xabier, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. For instance, you could run `dput(tacsatB)` and add the result to your question. If your data are too large, use `dput(head(tacsatB), n)` where n is the minimum number of rows needed to replicate your issue. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear how your question relates to the VMS family of operating systems. Why is the [`vms`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vms/info) tag applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
The function interpolteTacsat uses SI_DATIM column to calculate the interpolation, if it is already created will use it and if not, the function will create it in YEAR-Month-Day Hour:Minute format. If the one that is already created contains also seconds and they are not 00, it will give errors. So make sure you either delete SI_DATIM column and the function will create a new one, or keep the sI_DATIM column but with all the seconds 00.